# sendmail - how to unknown local user

Tags: sendmail

I'm using debian as my webserver and sendmail as my MTA
I do NOT have mydomain.com in the hosts file.
I have setup sendmail.cf with the following

```
dnl # Masquerading options
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`mydomain.com')dnl
```

However user@mydomain is still being reported as an unknown user by sendmail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail by default auto-configures list of local email domains.
It can be tuned off by the following line in `sendmail.mc`:

```
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True')
```

You can check list of local email domains using

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
```

You can manually add domains to local email domains via `/etc/mail/local-host-names` file (one domain per line).
`

Standard reminders:

- `sendmail.mc` needs recompilation into `sendmail.cf`
- sendmail daemon needs to be restarted or send HUP signal to see new version of `sendmail.cf`